# paint.setColor is darker than actual value

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-color

I am drawing circular border using the below **`Paint`** object using color code `"#D63333"` or `"#009933"`. I noticed that the border which gets created is darker than other images where I apply the same color code. Paint has a default black color and I am guessing somehow these are getting multiplied ?

How can I preserve the purity of the color.

```
    Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    borderPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    borderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

[image: Image1 with green color]
[image: Image 2 with Red color]

Comment: can you post the Image so will can get some clear Idea and post the `Image` color also..

Comment: I think that could the alpha value of the colors, check that, or set the same on both targets

Comment: Try borderPaint.setAlpha(0). may be this help you

Comment: @AndyDeveloper, that dint work.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti setting alpha value to 0 dint work.

Comment: try using #77009933 & #77D63333 as strokes color

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, that's more like hack. I should be able to pass the same color and get same output.